# Swift 5 Background upload not receiving http response headers and failing silently

Tags: ios, swift, urlsession

I've been working on a background file upload to Google Cloud with an iOS app using SwiftUI with Swift 5. I've gotten it to work successfully when everything is configured correctly, but it fails silently and reports success when I intentionally have things incorrectly configured (Incorrect address, bad auth token, etc.). It will even give me data sent updates for the entire upload even though it's not being received.

My question is: How do I get the correct HTTP response headers to tell me that the upload has failed?

Here is the code creating the background url session:

```
let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: Constants.URL_SESSION_IDENTIFIER)
configuration.sessionSendsLaunchEvents = true
configuration.sharedContainerIdentifier = "my-suite-name"
self.urlSession = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
```

Here is the code to upload the file:

```
func uploadFile(fileUrl: URL, token: String, contentType: String, uploadUrl: URL) {
    print("Uploading video")
    var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: uploadUrl)
    urlRequest.setValue(contentType, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    urlRequest.setValue("Bearer \(token)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
    urlSession.uploadTask(with: urlRequest, fromFile: fileUrl).resume()
  }
```

On the class (self) that is the delegate, I've implemented this protocol `URLSessionTaskDelegate` and added these two functions:

```
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didSendBodyData bytesSent: Int64, totalBytesSent: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToSend: Int64) { }

func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?) { }
```

These all work when it's configured correctly, but continue to work even when it's not configured correctly...I can't figure out a way to get them to let me know that the upload isn't actually being received or being rejected. If I try a similar upload with Postman it will immediately respond back with an error and stop running the upload, while this will still run.

I've tried implementing a couple other related protocols with some of their related functions but had no success. For example I found the `URLSessionDataDelegate` protocol has a function:

```
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, dataTask: URLSessionDataTask, didReceive: URLResponse) { }
```

Which is the only one in the family of URLSession Delegates that receives http headers that I can find, but it doesn't get triggered when running the uploads.

Thanks for your help and let me know if there is more information needed.

Comment: In `func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?) { }`, check `task.response as? HTTPURLResponse`, and its header, status code, etc.. The `error` parameter shouldn't contains the HTTP Errors code, but other kind of error, (ie, the request hasn't been made). The request did succeed, ie, it went from device to the URL, but getting rejected is not its "problem". It's "yours" to check.

Comment: That works great if at the end of the upload task, since that function is only called at the end, but is there any way to find that out before the entire upload completes?

Comment: If you get rejected with a 500 or any other error, the full upload shouldn’t happen. Imagine you have a sever, some illegally tries to upload unwanted data, you don’t want it.

Comment: Right now it's giving a 401 Not Authorized error since I'm intentionally giving an invalid Authorization token, but it is still running the entire upload before giving me the 401 response. Would that error be handled different than a 500 level error?